# Simple Javascript/CSS text overlay on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript

Here's an easy one but my web fu is rusty. I have a a list of small images (100px width, 125px height) I'd like users to be able to click on the image and in doing so have a number overlaid on the clicked image.

Is there a "easy" way to do this with just CSS and/or Javascript? I could use Javasript to add a class to the clicked image/div but not quite sure how to generate the transparent numeral overlay to fill the image area. do I need to draw to the Canvas or is there an easier way?

Comment: I *obviously* don't know what to try...hence the question. Looks like some helpful starting points listed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I get the question, as this should be pretty straight forward.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/za8n4/)

Is this what your trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can have transparent images with numbers on them if you don't have too many of them (e.g. if it's, say, under 100). Then just overlay them using different classes as you mention.

Comment: Why would you need an image?  Just use an div or something with a number in it.

Comment: @James Yes, agree, that's a good alternative. What comes to my mind as the possible advantage of images: CSS-only solution, no additional DOM elements and better styling of numbers if desired. Of course, it all depends on the usage.